# Relation between grammar and operator associativity

Tags: parsing, operator-keyword, associativity

Some compiler books / articles / papers talk about design of a grammar and the relation of its operator's associativity. I'm a big fan of top-down, especially recursive descent, parsers and so far most (if not all) compilers I've written use the following expression grammar:

```
Expr   ::= Term { ( "+" | "-" ) Term }
Term   ::= Factor { ( "*" | "/" ) Factor }
Factor ::= INTEGER | "(" Expr ")"
```

which is an EBNF representation of this BNF:

```
Expr  ::= Term Expr'
Expr' ::= ( "+" | "-" ) Term Expr' | ε
Term  ::= Factor Term'
Term' ::= ( "*" | "/" ) Factor Term' | ε
Factor = INTEGER | "(" Expr ")"
```

According to what I read, some regards this grammar as being "wrong" due to the change of operator associativity (left to right for those 4 operators) proven by the growing parse tree to the right instead of left. For a parser implemented through attribute grammar, this might be true as l-attribute value requires that this value created first then passed to child nodes. however, when implementing with normal recursive descent parser, it's up to me whether to construct this node first then pass to child nodes (top-down) or let child nodes be created first then add the returned value as the children of this node (passed in this node's constructor) (bottom-up). There should be something I miss here because I don't agree with the statement saying this grammar is "wrong" and this grammar has been used in many languages esp. Wirthian ones. Usually (or all?) the reading that says it promotes LR parsing instead of LL.

Comment: Would be interesting to know where you read that this is "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is that a language has an *abstract syntax* which is just like:

```
E ::= E + E | E - E | E * E | E / E | Int | (E)
```

but this is actually implemented via a *concrete syntax* which is used to specify associativity and precedence. So, if you're writing a recursive decent parse, you're implicitly writing the concrete syntax into it as you go along and that's fine, though it may be good to specify it exactly as a phrase-structured grammar as well!

There are a couple of issues with your grammar if it is to be a fully-fledged concrete grammar. First of all, you need to add productions to just 'go to the next level down', so relaxing your syntax a bit:

```
Expr ::= Term + Term | Term - Term | Term
Term ::= Factor * Factor | Factor / Factor | Factor
Factor ::= INTEGER | (Expr)
```

Otherwise there's no way to derive valid sentences starting from the start symbol (in this case Expr). For example, how would you derive '1 * 2' without those extra productions?

```
Expr -> Term
     -> Factor * Factor
     -> 1 * Factor
     -> 1 * 2
```

We can see the other grammar handles this in a slightly different way:

```
Expr -> Term Expr'
     -> Factor Term' Expr'
     -> 1 Term' Expr'
     -> 1 * Factor Term' Expr'
     -> 1 * 2 Term' Expr'
     -> 1 * 2 ε Expr'
     -> 1 * 2 ε ε
      = 1 * 2
```

but this achieves the same effect.

Your parser is actually non-associative. To see this ask how `E + E + E` would be parsed and find that it couldn't. Whichever `+` is consumed first, we get `E` on one side and `E + E` on the other, but then we're trying to parse `E + E` as a `Term` which is not possible. Equivalently, think about deriving that expression from the start symbol, again not possible.

```
Expr -> Term + Term
     -> ? (can't get another + in here)
```

The other grammar is left-associative ebcase an arbitrarily long sting of `E + E + ... + E` can be derived.

So anyway, to sum up, you're right that when writing the RDP, you can implement whatever *concrete* version of the *abstract* syntax you like and you probably know a lot more about that than me. But there are these issues when trying to produce the grammar which describes your RDP precisely. Hope that helps!

Comment: I did encounter the problem when trying to re-implement my EBNF based RDP to a parser generator which only accepts BNF, and I neither used the explicit associativity feature nor the abstract syntax. Perhaps the solution would be to start using them.

Comment: Yeah, if you use Yacc for example, that has special options for associativity and you can basically just provide the abstract syntax context free grammar. Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1):

To get associative trees, you really need to have the trees formed with the operator as the subtree root node, with children having similar roots.

Your implementation grammar:

```
Expr  ::= Term Expr'
Expr' ::= ( "+" | "-" ) Term Expr' | ε
Term  ::= Factor Term'
Term' ::= ( "*" | "/" ) Factor Term' | ε
Factor ::= INTEGER | "(" Expr ")"
```

must make that awkward; if you implement recursive descent on this, the Expr' routine has no access to the "left child" and so can't build the tree.  You can always patch this up by passing around pieces (in this case, passing tree parts up the recursion) but that just seems awkward.   You could have chosen this instead as a grammar:

```
Expr  ::= Term  ( ("+"|"-") Term )*;
Term  ::= Factor ( ( "*" | "/" ) Factor )* ;
Factor ::= INTEGER | "(" Expr ")"
```

which is just as easy (easier?) to code recursive descent-wise, but now you can form the trees you need without trouble.

This doesn't *really* get you associativity; it just shapes the trees so that it could be allowed.  Associativity means that the tree  ( + (+ a b) c) means the same thing as (+ a (+ b c)); its actually a semantic property (sure doesn't work for "-" but the grammar as posed can't distinguish).

We have a tool (the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html)) that includes parsers *and* term-rewriting (using source-to-source transformations) in which the associativity is explicitly expressed.  We'd write your grammar:

```
Expr  ::= Term ;
[Associative Commutative] Expr  ::= Expr "+" Term ;
Expr  ::= Expr "-" Term ;
Term  ::= Factor ;
[Associative Commutative] Term  ::= Term "*" Factor ;
Term  ::= Term "/" Factor ;
Factor ::= INTEGER ;
Factor ::= "(" Expr ")" ;
```

The grammar seems longer and clumsier this way, but it in fact allows us to break out the special cases and mark them as needed.  In particular, we can now distinguish operators that are associative from those that are not, and mark them accordingly.  With that semantic marking, our tree-rewrite engine automatically accounts for associativity and commutativity.  You can see a [full example of such DMS rules being used to symbolically simplify high-school algebra](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html) using explicit rewrite rules over a typical  expression grammar  that don't have to account for such semantic properties. That is built into the rewrite engine.

Comment: yes, indeed the EBNF version is an improvement from both design and implementation point of view. I actually try to avoid left recursive solution with associativity explicitly specified (as how it's done in many parser generators). I'll take a look to that DMS tool, seems interesting :)