# Is left-to-right associativity guaranteed for a mixture of multiplication and division?

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence, associativity

<sub>Please note, that this has nothing to do with [Operator Precedence.. () and ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897934/operator-precedence-and) , [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) , [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc) and the hundreds similar questions about this here</sub>

---

**Shortly**: is the **Associativity** guaranteed by the standard?

**Detailed example**: from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence)'s article for operator precedence, `operator*` and `operator/` have the same priority and they are `Left-to-right` operators. Does this mean, that *the standard **guarantees***, that this:

```
int res = x / y * z / t;
```

will be evaluated as

```
int res = ( ( x / y ) * z ) / t;
```

or it's implementation defined?

If it's guaranteed, could you quote?

---

<sub>It's just out of curiosity, I always write brackets in these cases.</sub>
<sub>Ready to delete the question, if there's such one.</sub>

Comment: Yes (now need a few for characters!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the latest publicly available [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3376.pdf)

**5.6 Multiplicative operators [expr.mul]**

> 1 The multiplicative operators *, /, and % group left-to-right.
>
> ```
> multiplicative-expression:
> pm-expression
> multiplicative-expression * pm-expression
> multiplicative-expression / pm-expression
> multiplicative-expression % pm-expression
> ```

So parsing will go like:

```
int res = x / y * z / t;
int res = (x / y * z) / t;
int res = ((x / y) * z) / t;
```

Comment: And not like `int res = ( x / y ) * z / t; int res = ( ( x / y ) * z ) / t;`? I have some troubles understanding that order. If so, why? Could you explain (and I'll accept the answer)

Comment: I see, that the result is the same, just asking :)

Comment: If you look at the parse tree: it's `multiplicative-expression: multiplicative-expression @ pm-expression`. When parsing your expression, the rightmost term `t` is isolated as the `pm-expression`, and the rest is then evaluated as another `multiplicative-expression`. The next step will identify `z` as the `pm-experssion`.

Comment: what does `pm-expression` mean?

Comment: On how to read expresssion grammars, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148705/relation-between-grammar-and-operator-associativity

Comment: @KirilKirov `pm-expression` is a plus or minus expression. It makes sure that multiplication/division/modulo have higher precedence than addition/substraction

Comment: To explain this who have not been introduced to formal grammars: This text from the standard states that a multiplicative-expression (which I will abbreviate “ME”) must be formed of either a pm-expression (“PE”) or one of the following combinations: “ME * PE”, “ME / PE”, “ME % PE”. For our purposes, identifiers such as “x” and “y“ are already PEs. To form an ME from “x / y * z”, you must make the “x / y” into an ME, then use that ME to form “ME * z” into another ME. You cannot form “y * z” into an ME first, because that would give you “x / ME”, and since x is a PE, it would be “PE / ME”.…

Comment: Yes in your case. But in  `x / y * z / (u+v)`, the `u+v` would be a `pm-expression`.

Comment: However, there is no rule in the grammar that says “PE / ME” can be an “ME” (or any other object in the grammar), so you cannot form the expression this way. Therefore, the grammar compels left-to-right association in these operators.

Comment: TO summarize: because we have `ME @ PE`, (PE to the right of @), any multiplicative @ evaluates left-to-right.

Comment: @KirilKirov NP, nice question! (BTW, I always put parentheses everywhere just to avoid errors and confusion)

Comment: @rhalbersma - yeah, me too (I wrote it in the question, too). I asked just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 5):

n3337 5.6/1

**The multiplicative operators *, /, and % group left-to-right.**

Read 5 par of standard.